# sending email via mailgun api

Tags: node.js, email, mailgun

I'm trying to send an email via Mailgun API on node js using the Mailgun library, But the email going to the spam folder, Also I added the DNS Provided to the domain, On the template code there is unsubscribe button.

```
let apiKey = 'API-KEY';
let domain = 'Domain';
let mailgun = require('mailgun-js')({apiKey, domain});
let email = "Email";
let dataa = {
from: '"medialocal" <no-reply@market.medialocal.com>',
to: email,
subject: 'Media local',
html: htmlCode,
subscribed: true,
};
mailgun.messages().send(dataa, function (error, body) {
console.log(body)
})
```